# How to write Linq Binary type to MemoryStream and vice versa

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, binary, memorystream

I'm going to write `System.Data.Linq.Binary` value to `MemoryStream` and perform some manipulations, then re-write new values from `MemoryStream` to `Binary`! how to do?

Comment: May i know the reason for down vote of my answer please, though not praticulary discussing about MemoryStream ? Because it could help me to improve. :-)

Comment: @Siva because i want to write Binary to MemoryStream and vice versa not convert to string and vice versa!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a `Binary` instance, because it's immutable (the MSDN documentation says: *"Represents an immutable block of binary data."*). But you can assign a new value to a `Binary` variable:

```
Binary binary = ...

// Binary to MemoryStream
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(binary.ToArray());

...

// MemoryStream to binary
binary = stream.ToArray(); // implicit conversion from byte[] to Binary
```